# How to handle negative case of Flux filterWhen()?

Tags: java, project-reactor

How to make async non-blocking call in case filterWhen() is false?

I have a Flux of items coming from SQS. In some cases I need to filter them out, but after filtration I still need to send an event to 3rd party api with item details.

The code looks like this:

```
getItems()
  .map(this::doSomething)
  .flatMap(item -> callService1(item).thenReturn(item))
  .filterWhen(item -> check(item))
  .flatMap(item -> callService2(item))
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
getItems()
  .map(this::doSomething)
  .flatMap(item -> callService1(item).thenReturn(item))
  .filterWhen(item -> check(item))
  .ifFalse(item -> 3rdPartyApi(item))
  .flatMap(item -> callService2(item))
```

is there any operator I can use to replace the line with **ifFalse()** or use another approach?

if it was simple if, we could probably use flatMap and do the checking within that. But its filterWhen() and can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to attach that side API call to the publisher used as the `filterWhen` "condition" (build on top of the `check(...)` call) when the result emitted by `check` publisher is `false`:

```
Mono<Boolean> check(String s) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> s.contains("example"));
}

Mono<Long> sideEffectOnFiltered(String s) {
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .doOnNext(b -> System.out.println("did side effect on " + s));
}

@Test
void demonstrateIfFalse() {
    Flux.just("example", "value", "example2")
        .filterWhen(v -> check(v)
            .flatMap(isExample -> isExample ? Mono.just(true) :
                sideEffectOnFiltered(v).thenReturn(false)
            )
    )
        .log()
        .blockLast();
}
```

This outputs:

```
11:03:45.640 [main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FilterWhen.1 - onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.FluxFilterWhenSubscriber)
11:03:45.646 [main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FilterWhen.1 - request(unbounded)
11:03:45.704 [main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FilterWhen.1 - onNext(example)
did side effect on value
11:03:47.726 [parallel-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FilterWhen.1 - onNext(example2)
11:03:47.730 [parallel-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FilterWhen.1 - onComplete()
```

Comment: Simon Basle, thank you. will this still be async and non-blocking? and in case it is flatMapSequential() will that work as expected even it's inside filterWhen()?

Comment: if you're talking about `flatMapSequential` inside the filterWhen, it wouldn't make much sense here because only the first value of the `Publisher<Boolean>` passed to `filterWhen` is used. as part of the main sequence, before filterWhen: no problem. And yes, this is all still reactive and non-blocking :)

Comment: `.filterWhen(sku -> beerAttrisRepo.existsById(sku.getId()).map(b -> !b))` like this